# decode percent-encoded string c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

How do I decode a string like the following:

name1=ABC&userId=DEF&name2=zyx&payload=%3cSTAT+xmlns%3axsi%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema-instance%22%3e%3cREQ...

Background:  I'm accepting an HTTP POST (name value pairs, basically) then converting the byte array to string with:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length);
```

I've tried the HtmlDecode method of WebUtility and HttpUtility but appear to get the same string back.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(str)
```

Comment: Thanks to all.  Both answers get me where I need to go!  Are there particular pros/cons of the Uri method vs. the HttpUtility method?

Comment: Uri will allow you to exclude System.Web from your references if you don't need it otherwise.

Comment: @JohnSpiegel: Yes there is a subtle difference, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`?

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx).

Note that this function doesn't do quite the same thing as `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`.

Edit: In answer to the question about differences between `UrlDecode` and `UnescapeDataString`:

To quote the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx) on `UnescapeDataString`:

> Many Web browsers escape spaces inside of URIs into plus ("+") characters; however, the UnescapeDataString method does not convert plus characters into spaces because this behavior is not standard across all URI schemes.

`UrlDecode` does handle these though, you get different responses if you try the following:

```
string a = Uri.UnescapeDataString(".Net+Framework"); //returns ".Net+Framework"
string b = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(".Net+Framework"); //returns ".Net Framework"
```

Therefore it would seem that, for better coverage, HttpUtility.UrlDecode is the better option.

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlDecode has a second paramater to accept an Encoding that should support the characters the escaped string contains. That would look like this: `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Message, Encoding.Latin1)` for any Microsoft/ISO sets.

Answer (score 3):

[HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("name1=ABC&userId=DEF&name2=zyx&payload=%3cSTAT+xmlns%3axsi%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema-instance%22%3e%3cREQ...");
```

gives

```
name1=ABC&userId=DEF&name2=zyx&payload=<STAT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><REQ...
```

and I expect that is what you want.