# Convert url-like string to xml string in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am sending xml/mathml as data in my AJAX request, and at the server side in C# I get this sort of text:

```
%3Cmath%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmrow%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmsub%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmi%3Ex%3C%2Fmi%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmtext%3E12%3C%2Fmtext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmsub%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

So, basically it is xml, but the xml basic characters are converted to url like characters, %20, %3E, %0A etc...

I have this POST method in my API controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostUpload(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    string jsonContent = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Utility.Utility.WriteLineToConsole("json data post: " + jsonContent);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonContent);
}
```

The Utility function WriteLineToConsole() prints the jsonContent and the top text among the result.

How can i covert the string above to xml, i.e replace the url-like characters to xml characters?

Note: I am using MVC 4 / C# , jQuery AJAX, and both contentType and dataType are of type json. I want my data object to be like

```
data:{mathml: "<math>...</math>"}
```

Comment: That looks like it's `urlencode`d.  Try `Server.Decode(thatString);` or `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(thatString)` or `Uri.UnescapeDataString(thatString)`

Comment: Seems contentType is not properly set in ajax call. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535872/http-post-xml-data-in-c-sharp)

Comment: BTW, why are you setting it to json when you're obviously sending xml?  Seems `application/xml; charset=UTF-8` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Kyle, `Uri.UnescapeDataString` will work well - https://dotnetfiddle.net/zLkawf. Could even be marked as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898556/decode-percent-encoded-string-c-sharp-net, I guess.

Comment: I think you need to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode & System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode. Html won't except certain special characters : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(thatString)
```

did the job